# FASTECDSA : Module Not FoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin

when i try to run a python script it throws me **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "fastecdsa"** error and when i try to install fastecdsa it throws me this

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for fastecdsa, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: fastecdsa
Running setup.py install for fastecdsa ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for fastecdsa did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [41 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.10
creating build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
copying fastecdsa\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
copying fastecdsa\curve.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
copying fastecdsa\ecdsa.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
copying fastecdsa\keys.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
copying fastecdsa\point.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
copying fastecdsa\util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
copying fastecdsa_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa
creating build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\encoding
copying fastecdsa\encoding\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\encoding
copying fastecdsa\encoding\der.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\encoding
copying fastecdsa\encoding\pem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\encoding
copying fastecdsa\encoding\sec1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\encoding
copying fastecdsa\encoding\util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\encoding
copying fastecdsa\encoding_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\encoding
creating build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_brainpool_ecdh.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_keygen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_key_export_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_key_recovery.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_nonce_generation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_p256_ecdsa.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_point.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_prehashed.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_prime_field_curve_math.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_rfc6979_ecdsa.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_whitespace_parsing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests\test_whycheproof_vectors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
copying fastecdsa\tests_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests
creating build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests\encoding
copying fastecdsa\tests\encoding\test_der.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests\encoding
copying fastecdsa\tests\encoding\test_sec1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests\encoding
copying fastecdsa\tests\encoding_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\fastecdsa\tests\encoding
running build_ext
building 'fastecdsa.curvemath' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> fastecdsa

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

my attempt to import the fastecdsa module is because i have written a script that creates many Divided Pubkeys with the bit reduction specified
the division is achieved using the modular inverse of the scalar at least 1 of the output pubkeys with have the reduced bit range specified in the argument how do i resolve this..?

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

Comment: Simply, read the error and it tells you what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, that pip modules requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater.

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools [end of output]`

Install here: [Visual C++](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)